# Rails: Postgres handling where clause – error in JSON format

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi I have a model `books` with below mentioned method:

```
def self.text_search(query)
    pry
    if query.present?
        where("title @@ :q or author @@ :q", q: query)
    else
        find(-1)
    end
end
```

In my controller, I send respond to client as JSON:

```
render json: @books
```

This code works fine if the query returns something. If not, I am not able to send a JSON response. I get a `template missint error`.
How can I handle it in JSON?

I tried

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @books = Book.text_search(params[:query])
        @author= Author.find(Shelf.find(@books.map(&:isbn).uniq).map(&:author_id))
        rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound  #donothing

        render json: @books
    end
end
```

Comment: Can you show the controller action also ?

Comment: Hi Arup I have updated the question with controller. I realised that the issue is with my next database call.

Comment: Are you having to rescue because of find(-1)?

Comment: no find(-1) give an empty book list. If Shelf has not books with the isbn we picked from books then , and for author I want to handle it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like the thought from tobmatth. However, I also believe you should avoid throwing (and handling) exceptions in the normal (expected) flow of your code.

So, I'd also suggest something like:

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @books = Book.text_search(params[:query])
    if @books.count > 0
      @author= Author.find(Shelf.find(@books.map(&:isbn).uniq).map(&:author_id))
    end

    render json: @books

  end
end
```

I think this would have worked with your original code (perhaps?).

Answer (score 3):

```
def self.text_search(query)
  if query.present?
    where("title @@ :q or author @@ :q", q: query)
  else
    Book.none
  end
end
```

should do the trick. Book.none returns an empty ActiveRecord::Relation.

In addition, i don't get why you assign authors while you only render @books.

```
@author= Author.find(Shelf.find(@books.map(&:isbn).uniq).map(&:author_id))
```

will raise ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound if no matching records present. Consider using `find_by id: []`

Comment: Hi tobmath thanks for Book.none trick will use it but it doesnt apply in this case I guess. I am passing a query so if query.present? is valid and where clause is executed. and in where clause finds nothing.Shelf.find is upset. and for that I am getting Missing template error. I can ignore and return only books but I dont know how to handle silently exception for Shelf.find

Comment: I don't know how your models are set up, but `@author = Author.find_by(id: Shelf.find(@books.map(&:isbn).uniq).map(&:author_id))` should work.